# No route matches for inherited (create) action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have 2 versions of my API(1&2) the controller of api version 2 inherits from the controller of api version 1. The problem is, specs for version 1 are running fine, but when i run specs in version 2, it tells me

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"api/mobile/v2/samples"}

```
#version 1
class Api::Mobile::V1::SamplesController < ApplicationController
  def create
   #dummy
  end
end

#version 2
require "meta_data"
class Api::Mobile::V2::SamplesController < Api::Mobile::V1::SamplesController
  include MetaData
end


#spec for version 1
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Api::Mobile::V1::SamplesController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "performs a post" do
      post :create
    end
  end
end

#spec for version 2
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Api::Mobile::V2::SamplesController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "performs a post" do
      post :create
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: do you have something like the following in your routes? `namespace :api do namespace :mobile do namespace :v2 resources :samples end end end`

Comment: Yes, the app is working fine. It is just the tests which I can't get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

RSpec is looking for `SamplesController` (plural). Make sure you are specifying your routes using singular `resource` if that's what you have. Otherwise, specify plural form of `sample` as `sample` in an initializer.

I would just go with the flow and user plural form. But, obviously with the public API that's a real headache.

Comment: Sry, this was just a copy&paste mistake from my sample code. I edited the code.

Comment: Did you define new routes for v2 in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Yes, the app is working fine. It is just the tests which I can't get up and running.